# Cant sign in to MSDN/Visual Studio in Unity after trial

Tags: unity

I've been using VS13 instead of Monodevelop for my Unity projects and my "30-day trial" has ended.  Apparently all I have to do is sign in with my MSDN account and it *should* let me continue using VS without having to pay $6,000.00, but when I try to sign in I get "something went wrong, try again later"... this has been happening since yesterday.  I have an active MSDN account that I am currently signed into and everything seems fine, should be a simple fix - hopefully.  I reaaaaalllllyyy don't wanna go back to Monodevelop... any suggestions?  It's only inside of Unity that I'm having this issue.

Comment: I am not sure this is the right site to ask, you probably better try ask on Microsoft support.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about an issue with your MSDN account, which is not specific to game development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this problem too but im unsure now what the fix was. Are you using the community or the pro version? You may have to get the community edition, which is free and has no trial period.

You should first try disabling your firewall and antivirus though and do the update again. Your pc may be blocking the update process. This seems more likely to me.

Another possiblity is that you have to login to msdn and change the license for your copy of vs2013. Try this second.

Sorry i dont have a specific answer. Power is out right now so i cant check in my pc.

Comment: Thanks, yeah I'm pretty sure I downloaded the community version.  Again, this literally only happens when I try to open a script in Unity.  I'll check the update settings... thanks again for the reply!  :)

Comment: That worked!  I did the update again, restarted and when I was prompted to log in - it logged me in.  Thanks again!  I appreciate it!  :)